# How to calculate the Cartesian product of two vectors in DolphinDB?

Tags: cartesian-product, dolphindb

I have used the following script to generate the Cartesian product of two vectors: the columns “order_book_ids” and “trading_dates” from two tables.

```
ordt=table(order_book_ids as id)
datet=table(trading_dates as dts)
tb=select id, dts from cj(ordt, datet)
list=()
for (i in 0..(size(tb)-1)){
    list.append!(tb[i].values())}
list
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cross` function is a better choice. You can try the script below:

```
flatten cross(def(x,y)->(x,y), 1 2 3, `A`B`C)
```

or

```
flatten cross(join, 1 2 3, `A`B`C)
```